# Имя класса в переменной

Tags: php, классы

```
namespace My\Namespace;

use ExtNamespace\FloatToInt;

class test
{

    function t ()
    {
    $class_a = 'FloatToInt';
    $class_b = 'ExtNamespace\FloatToInt';
    // $d = new FloatToInt() - работает.
    // $d = new $class_a() - не работает: Fatal error: Class 'FloatToInt' not found...
    // $d = new $class_b() - работает.
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как записать имя класса в переменную, не указывая полного пути к классу и почему не работает создание объекта при помощи new $class_a()? Ведь на первый взгляд, код во второй и третей строке идентичен:

```
1 $class_a = 'FloatToInt';
2 $d = new FloatToInt();
3 $d = new $class_a();
```

Comment: Создать так объект можно, у вас код просто класса FloatToInt не видит, путь ExtNamespace\FloatToInt корректен? Автозагрузка работает?

Comment: Да, путь корректен, объект без проблем создается так: $d = new FloatToInt(); а вот используя переменную, в которой содержится то же имя - ошибка класс не найден. Причем, если в переменную записать полный путь к классу: $class_b = 'ExtNamespace\FloatToInt'; то вызов $d = new $class_b() так же работает...

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел, как не удивительно, в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php):

> Если с директивой new используется строка (string), содержащая имя класса, то будет создан новый экземпляр этого класса. **Если имя находится в пространстве имен, то оно должно быть задано полностью.**

Весьма странное поведение, как по мне...

Comment: А по мне так достаточно логично. Все функции вроде get_class работают с полным именем класса, да и работать должно так, чтобы не использовать use, иначе все используемые классы нужно будет перечислить.