# Как вызвать метод у класса имея только название самого класса

Tags: php

Реализовываю в целях самообучения роутинг, по примеру лары, то есть с возможностью указать урл, контроллер и метод. Выглядит это так:

```
namespace App\Core\Routing;
class Routing
{
   //some codes
   public static function route($url, $action = "", $data = []){
        App::getPageController($action, $data);
        array_push(self::$list, [
            'uri' => $url,
            'action' => $action,
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

Собственно сам метод в котором я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
namespace App;
class App
{
   //some code
   static function getPageController($str, $data){
        if(!empty($str)){
            $controllerData = explode("@", $str);
            require_once Core::getControllersDirectory().$controllerData[0].'.php';
            $obj = new $controllerData[0];
//            call_user_func_array([$obj, $controllerData[1]], $data);
            $method = $controllerData[1];
            return $obj->$method($data);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

где вот этой строкой я ранее подключаю файл с этим классом

```
require_once Core::getControllersDirectory().$controllerData[0].'.php';
```

путь там правильный приходит.
Получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'WelcomeController' not found in E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\App\App.php
```

Подскажите как можно это реализовать и возможно ли это вообще? Если возможно - то скиньте ман или пример

=======UPD
Полный листинг ошибки

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WelcomeController' not found in E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\App\App.php:23 Stack trace: #0 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\App\Core\Routing\Routing.php(18): App\App::getPageController() #1 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\routes.php(3): App\Core\Routing\Routing::route() #2 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(71): require('E:\\web\\OpenServ...') #3 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(61): composerRequire144f2ff587452c15ee17a04d092c5306() #4 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit144f2ff587452c15ee17a04d092c5306::getLoader() #5 E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\index.php(2): require_once('E:\\web\\OpenServ...') #6 {main} thrown in E:\web\OpenServer\domains\latul.ths8.loc\App\App.php on line 23
```

Где line 23 - это эта строка `$obj = new $controllerData[0];`

Comment: а разве ругается не на эту строку `return $obj->$method($data);` а есть такой метод?

Comment: неймспейс небось есть у контроллера, который вы не указываете

Comment: Да есть, а как мне его динамически указать? Или для контроллера его не указывать?

Comment: положить в $controllerData[0]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547310/Имя-класса-в-переменной

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php



class AClass{
    public function methodA(){
        echo 'ok';
    }
    public static function methodB(){
        echo 'ok2';
    }
}



$b = 'methodA';
$a = new AClass();
$a->$b();
$b = 'methodB';
AClass::$b();
```

Comment: если интересовал синтаксис - то он такой -  мы не знаем метод - его название хранится в переменной

Answer (score 0):

Помогло указание namespace класса. Ответ выше, с записью метода не помог, хотя сам по себе - рабочий, так как классы находятся в разных файлах и пространствах.